# got an error in flutter require an identifier while using the streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, mobile-application

I have created the widget in flutter app and its connected with the google firebase but i got an error on the StreamBuilder while getting the data document.('quick')

```
Widget _createBody() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('notes').document.('quick').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          var doc = snapshot.data;
          if (doc.exists){
            return Text(doc['content']);
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();

       }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('notes').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Center(
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              );
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Loading...'),
                );
              default:
                return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((
                  DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return  ListTile(
                  title: Text(document['content']),
                 );
               }).toList(),
            }
           }
         };
```

Comment: Im using the "Dot" after the document. I got the solution. Thanks For You Interest

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this if you're fetching a single document.

```
Widget _createBody() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('notes')
          .document('quick')
          .get()
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          var doc = snapshot.data;
          if (doc.exists){
            return Text(doc['content']);
          }
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();

       }
    );
  }
```

If this doesn't work, you can always change it like so:

```
Firestore.instance
        .collection('notes')
        .document('quick')
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      // use ds as a snapshot
    });
```

Comment: let me check it